# stdout and stderr redirection to different files

Tags: shell, command-line, io-redirection, stdout, stderr

How can I redirect stdout to 2 different files and stderr to another, different file?

I want something like `<my_cmd> 1> file1 file2 2>file3`

I know:
`<my_cmd> | tee file1 file2 > /dev/null`

would redirect stdout to file1 and file2. 
But I also want stderr to be redirected to a different file. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Quick'n'dirty : `<my_cmd> 1> file1 2>file3; cp file1 file2`

Comment: @Httqm, please, don't post answers as comments, but as answers which can be voted on. Your suggestion is _not at all the same_, in particular, there will be no relevant content in `file2` until the command finishes!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should do:

```
<my_cmd> 2>file3 | tee file1 file2 > /dev/null
```

The stderr redirection is done first and then `tee` gets just stdout.

Comment: can simplify a touch: `cmd 2>file3 | tee file1 >file2`